# How can I get the command that was executed at the command line?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

If I call a script this way:

`myScript.sh -a something -b anotherSomething`

Within my script is there a way to get the command that called the script?

In my script on the first line I'm trying to use:

```
lastCommand=!!
echo $lastCommand
```

But the result is always null.

If I do `echo !!` the only thing that prints to the console is `!!`, but from the command line if I do `echo !!` I get the last command printed.

I've also tried:

`echo $BASH_COMMAND`

but I'm getting null here as well.  Is it because the script is called in a subshell and thus there is no previous command stored in memory for the subshell?

Comment: @jm666 this only returns the command that was executed, not the command and the parameters with their args.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full command which called the script would be `"$0" "$@"`, that is, the command itself followed by all the arguments quoted. This may *not* be the exact command which was run, but if the script is idempotent it can be run to get the same result:

```
$ cat myScript.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
printf '%q ' "$0" "$@"
printf '\n'
$ ./myScript.sh -a "foo bar" -b bar
./myScript.sh -a foo\ bar -b bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my script `myScript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
temp=`mktemp`
ps --pid $BASHPID -f > $temp 
lastCommand=`tail -n 1 $temp | xargs | cut -d ' ' -f 8-`
rm $temp
echo $lastCommand
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
last=`cat /proc/$$/cmdline | xargs -0`
echo $last
```